# List items don't vertical align properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a list of items with variable heights. When I try to make a neat list with items aligned in horizontal rows it all goes well when the list items all have the same height. When 1 or more items have a greater height it goes wrong. I created a JSFiddle to show the problem very clearly. Can anyone help me out?

http://jsfiddle.net/NNLDn/

my html:

```
<div>
    <ol>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li style="height: 140px;"></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

my css:

```
div {
    width: 730px;
}

ol {
    width 730px;
    margin-left: -40px;
}

ol li {
    display: block;
    width: 167px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 15px;

    background:red;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting the effective height of each row to be determined by the tallest element in the row?

Comment: li's wrapping to the next line is intentional?

Comment: Yes indeed! Each row should be the height of the highest element.

Comment: @kinakuta he didn't say it needed to be only one row...

Comment: are the items known before hand or are they dynamic? (coming from a database, etc)

Comment: The items come from a database and are images.

Comment: see @xpy's answer below, I think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`, then you can also play with the vertical alignment of the elements with `vertical-align`.

Comment: Example code included in your answer along with a demo go a long way around here.  Here's a free demo because you beat me to it:  http://jsfiddle.net/NNLDn/2/

Comment: Yeah, this looks like the best solution. Example with top vertical alignment: http://jsfiddle.net/zjhqP/

Answer (score 1):

The only css solution I know, if you know the number of `li` items per row, is to enclose each row in a div, and then float these divs. That way each div with automatically adjust to the height of the tallest li, and none of the floating `li`s will get "hung-up"

`div div {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/NNLDn/1/

Comment: That's where I was going as well

Answer (score 0):

I can't double check easily now, as I am in my phone, but I think you need to use `display:inline-block` and not use `float`